# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in - Only in wordpress, not outside of it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

**And now it works. With the help of Peter.**

I am trying to include a php file in wordpress. This is gathering data from a DB outside of the standard WP database, and when I try running the page alone it works fine, but as soon as I include in WP it gives me the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in app/resultat.php on line 19.

The code from the page:

```
    include 'con.php';

// error_reporting(-1); // reports all errors
// ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // shows all errors
// ini_set("log_errors", 1);
// ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");

// set the PDO error mode to exception
// $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function resultat() {

    global $conn;

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT navn, team, art, vaegt, dato FROM indvejninger ORDER by art, vaegt DESC");
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo $arr['navn'] . " ";
            echo " ";
            echo $arr['team'] . " ";
            echo $arr['art'] . " ";
            echo $arr['vaegt'] . " ";
            echo $arr['dato'] . "<br> ";
        }

    }

resultat();
```

I am well aware of my issue that the connection in "con.php" is somehow not known in resultat.php.
But I am totally lost as how to address the issue, can somebody please help?

Code from con.php:

```
$hostname = "*"; 
$database = "*"; 
$username = "*";          
$password = "*";          
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
); 

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password, $options);
```

I was trying to rewrite my con.php to a class instead, but that did not remove the issue.

Comment: Does changing `function resultat() {` to `function resultat() use($conn) {` and then remove the `global` work? Or pass it directly as a parameter to `resultat()`, so `resultat($conn)`, and again remove the `global`

Comment: Thanks @PeterFeatherstone, adding resultat($conn) helped. Now it works.

Comment: I wouldn't change the original question as you have done because people won't see the original error in case they are having similar problems...

Comment: Edited it back again, and once again, thanks.

Comment: No problem @Lasser I'm just glad it works for you now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already including the file so that means you have access to the `$conn` variable so there is no need for the global (and globals should be avoided in general anyway).

You should just be able to directly pass in the `$conn` variable to your `resultat` function and do away with the global as below:

```
function resultat($conn) {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT navn, team, art, vaegt, dato FROM indvejninger ORDER by art, vaegt DESC");
  $stmt->execute();

  while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo $arr['navn'] . " ";
      echo " ";
      echo $arr['team'] . " ";
      echo $arr['art'] . " ";
      echo $arr['vaegt'] . " ";
      echo $arr['dato'] . "<br> ";
  }
}

resultat($conn);
```